# Customized function in R, reduce number of arguments due to relatedness

Tags: r

I wrote a function to make scatter plots, using varying parameters/arguments:

```
f_plot = function(data, domain, y, z, x_title_label, y_title_label, timepoint) {
  
  item_dscrption = case_when(z == "ITEM1" ~ "Item 1 - Bloated Severity",
                             z == "ITEM2" ~ "Item 2 - Bloated Frequency",
                             z == "ITEM3" ~ "Item 3 - Eating",
                             z == "ITEM4" ~ "Item 4 - Tired",
                             z == "ITEM5" ~ "Item 5 - Breathing",
                             z == "ITEM6" ~ "Item 6 - Sleeping",
                             z == "ITEM7" ~ "Item 7 - Mobility",
                             z == "ITEM8" ~ "Item 8 - Comfort")
  
  domain_description = case_when(domain == "spring" ~ "Spring Season",
                                 domain == "summer" ~ "Summer Season",
                                 domain == "fall" ~ "Fall Season",
                                 domain == "winter" ~ "Winter Season")
  
  plot_data = data %>%
    filter(ABCD_domain == domain) 
  
  p = ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = ABCD_score, y = {{y}})) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, color = "#0433ff", size = 0.7) +
    ggpubr::stat_cor(aes(label = ..r.label..), label.x = 5.5, label.y = 4.5) +
    labs(x = paste0("Domain Score, ", domain_description, " (", timepoint, ")"),
         y = paste0(item_dscrption, " (", timepoint, ")")) +
    theme_bw()
  
  # Save the plot to a file (e.g., in PNG format)
  ggsave(filename = paste0("Item_", y_title_label, "_", domain, "_", timepoint, ".png"), plot = p, width = 4.5, height = 4.5, dpi = 500)
  
}

# To call the function:
f_plot(data = data, domain = "spring", y = ITEM1, z = "ITEM1", y_title_label = "1", timepoint = "Baseline")
```

As you can see, 3 of the function arguments are actually related: `y`, `z`, and `y_title_label` - when `y` is `ITEM1`, `z` should be `"ITEM1"` (with double quotes), and `y_title_label` would be the number which is `1`.

My question is, is there any way I can reduce these 3 arguments to just 1 since they're related? My toy dataframe is provided below.

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(
    "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002",
    "1006", "1006", "1006", "1006",
    "2170", "2170", "2170", "2170",
    "2166", "2166", "2166", "2166",
    "2168", "2168", "2168", "2168",
    "1003", "1003", "1003", "1003",
    "2169", "2169", "2169", "2169",
    "1005", "1005", "1005", "1005",
    "2165", "2165", "2165", "2165",
    "2171", "2171", "2171", "2171",
    "1004", "1004", "1004", "1004"
  ),
  ABCD_score = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3),
  ABCD_domain = c(
    "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter",
    "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter",
    "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter",
    "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter",
    "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter", "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter",
    "spring", "summer", "fall", "winter"
  ),
  ITEM1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your function to

```
f_plot = function(data, domain, y, x_title_label, timepoint) {
  y <- enquo(y)
  z <- rlang::quo_name(y)
  y_title_label <- stringr::str_extract(z, "\\d+")
  ...
}
```

which you can all like

```
f_plot(data = data, domain = "spring", y = ITEM1, timepoint = "Baseline")
```

The `enquo()` will turn the symbol into a quosure. Then you can get the string version of that with `quo_name` and you can extract the numeric part with `str_extract`.

Comment: I have a follow-up question, what if I pass the argument as ITEM1 in the function and I would like to get "ITEM1" somewhere inside the function? In other words, here you showed me how to add double quotes to ITEM1, what about the opposite?

Answer (score 2):

Yess you can do that. just pass in `y` and get the rest from within the function:

```
my_fun <- function(other_parameters, y, more_parameters){
  z <- as.character(substitute(y))
  y_title_label <- readr::parse_number(z)
     :
     :
}
```